# What are the types of bus routes data, which are made available from Open Street Map (OSM)?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, streets

With regards to bus routes, what are the types of data which are made available for download. Is it possible to export a region's bus routes in open street map (OSM) or GIS data format?

Comment: This will depend heavily on the country/region/city. I can think of many places that probably have such things available, and many that probably don't... Ref. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Buses

Answer (score 2):

For viewing bus routes you can take a look at OSM-based maps which visualize bus routes. The OSM wiki has a [list of public transport maps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Public_transport#Maps), for example the [transport layer at the front page](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#layers=TN) or the [Öpnvkarte](http://%C3%B6pnvkarte.de/).

For retrieving bus route data you can use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) or the nice frontend [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/). Use this query for retrieving all bus routes in the currently visible area:

```
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <query type="relation">
    <has-kv k="route" v="bus"/>
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
  </query>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

Answer (score 1):

These pages on the OSM Wiki will help you determine the necessary tags for the data you need:

> [Bus Stop, Stations, etc](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dbus_stop)
>
> [Bus Routes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routes#Bus_routes_.28also_trolley_bus.29)

You can see what actual data is available in your area of interest by using the [OSM Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) Tool. Use the Wizard to create a subset of the available data using the tags described above